# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to import tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've seen other people having UnicodeDecodeErrors with tf, but it always seems to be because they're trying to read a file with non-latin characters. I'm getting this error just from doing "import tensorflow", so I'm not sure where my error is coming from.

I'm using Python 3.6.5, running Windows 10, and installed Tensorflow through pip, so it should be the latest stable release.

Here is the error I'm getting just from trying to "import tensorflow":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 390, in find_cookie
    line_string = line.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 10: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 474, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\activations\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.activations import elu
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import activations
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\activations.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.utils.generic_utils import deserialize_keras_object
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.engine.training import Model
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\_impl\keras\callbacks.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.summary import summary as tf_summary
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\summary.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.summary_ops import tensor_summary
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\summary_ops.py", line 87, in <module>
    ops.NotDifferentiable("TensorSummary")
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2456, in NotDifferentiable
    _gradient_registry.register(None, op_type)
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\registry.py", line 67, in register
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\traceback.py", line 207, in extract_stack
    stack = StackSummary.extract(walk_stack(f), limit=limit)
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\traceback.py", line 358, in extract
    f.line
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\traceback.py", line 282, in line
    self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\linecache.py", line 136, in updatecache
    with tokenize.open(fullname) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 454, in open
    encoding, lines = detect_encoding(buffer.readline)
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 431, in detect_encoding
    encoding = find_cookie(first)
  File "C:\Users\jp11cy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tokenize.py", line 395, in find_cookie
    raise SyntaxError(msg)
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'C:\\Users\\jp11cy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\keras\\_impl\\keras\\utils\\__init__.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved through reinstallation of Tensorflow.